# Can I have recursive function call inside parallel streams in java

Tags: java

I have a function to model my Data.
If the parameter "Entity" contains child, it is enclosed in child names. 
There are two types of child Type-A & Type-B.
For Each type the function is called recursively.
This recursive function call exits when the child do not have any more child names.

```
public void modelMyData(Entity entity) {

    if (entity.getChildNames()[0] != null) {
        Arrays.stream(entity.getChildNames())
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                .parallelStream()
                .forEach(childType -> {

                        entity.getChild(childType).parallelStream()
                                .forEach(child -> {
                                    modelMyData(child);

                                    });
                        ;
                    });
    }

    System.out.println("INSERT " + entity.getChildAttributeValue());

}
```

The program works fine for me. But the use of parallel stream is said to be bad in java programming.

Visit http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-parallel-streams-are-bad-for-your-health/

Should I use streams instead of parallel streams?

Comment: make performance test to see if parallelStream will perform better on your machine

Comment: I already did that and streams gave me better performance than parallel streams. This confused me.

Comment: So use plain streams. Parallel streams would be useful if you perform some kind of IO during processing or/and long-running calculations which you'd like to parallelize among cores.

Comment: @AkhilKKamal if you have local I/O you may cause too many non-sequential accesses, which bring down performance for both HDDs and SSDs.

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing long-running operations in your streams? If yes, use parallelStream, if not, don't. Have you read the article? It refers to thread pool exhaustion during long-running operations. Is this the case for your problem/program?

As an aside, simply do `Arrays.asList(entity.getChildNames()).parallelStream()....`, no need to copy everything.

Comment: My uses cases has I/O operations, so it is recommended that I should go for parallel streams.

Comment: The question you linked to is about arrays of primitives, but that does not apply to your case, as the child names are objects (you test for equality with null)